# Function Call Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb, x86-64, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to reproduce a buffer overflow attack [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/33698.pdf) and I'm stuck with the implementation of the shell code as I get a segmentation fault when I assemble and execute it.

[image]

Seeing what GDB says, it seems to fail when it comes to call function `_readfile`. How can I fix this?

Comment: I might be reading that wrong but it seems you have an infinite loop (at least until the stack is exhausted) calling `_readfile` from itself?

Comment: You assembled it wrong, or it has been overwritten in memory. At `_start` you should already have a `jmp _push_filename` not a `jmp _readfile` and `_readfile` itself should start with a `pop rdi` not a `call`.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'll try. Sorry for my late reply.

Comment: The link became inaccessible, so the question post remains a little sence. That is why on Stack Overflow we want a code being the question post, not linked.